# golang chanel not working with sync.WaitGroup

Tags: go, async-await

my code

```golang
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "sync"
)

func other(c chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
   c <- 455
   wg.Done()
}

func addInt(c chan int, d int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
   c <- d
   wg.Done()
}
func main() {

   var wg sync.WaitGroup
   myChanel := make(chan int)

   wg.Add(2)

   go addInt(myChanel, 5, &wg)
   go other(myChanel, &wg)

   wg.Wait()

   c := 0


   for v := range myChanel {
       if c == 1 {

           close(myChanel)
       }
       fmt.Println(v)
       c++

   }

}
```

I am learning golang looking at mines, but it is true I got such an error. I looked at other sources. I couldn't reach a healthy solution. I tried shutdown (Chanel) again.

**error output**

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc0000140f8)
        /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x42
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc0000140f0)
        /usr/lib/go-1.13/src/sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x64
main.main()
        /home/zeus/go/src/github.com/awesomeProject/pool.go:27 +0xe4

goroutine 6 [chan send]:
main.addInt(0xc000016120, 0x5, 0xc0000140f0)
        /home/zeus/go/src/github.com/awesomeProject/pool.go:14 +0x3f
created by main.main
        /home/zeus/go/src/github.com/awesomeProject/pool.go:24 +0xaa

goroutine 7 [chan send]:
main.other(0xc000016120, 0xc0000140f0)
        /home/zeus/go/src/github.com/awesomeProject/pool.go:9 +0x37
created by main.main
        /home/zeus/go/src/github.com/awesomeProject/pool.go:25 +0xd6
exit status 2
```

Comment: Your code tries to send 2 values on the channel and only try to receive from if after that. On an unbuffered channel even the first send would block. Also the senders should close the channel, not the receiver. If there are multiple senders, there should be a coordinated goroutine closing it (if you want to use `for range` over the channel). What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/EjonbBYfCa1

try run

Comment: @dılosürücü compare with https://play.golang.org/p/Whj2ccwIw9I

Comment: @dılosürücü Yes, I tried. It's the same code as in your question. What is it you want to achieve with your code?

Answer (score 2):

You have an unbuffered channel, which means you can't send on it until there is something waiting to receive.

So when you do:

```
wg.Wait()
```

before you do

```
for v := range myChanel
```

you'll never be able to get to the receiver.

I've never needed to use a waitgroup when using unbuffered channels anyways, in my experience you only need them when doing concurrent stuff *without* channels.  You can just do it like this: https://play.golang.org/p/-SUuXGlFd1E

Comment: With multiple senders it's typical to use a WaitGroup to close the channel properly: `go func() { wg.Wait(); close(ch) }()`. In real code the number of elements to receive isn't usually known in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ı solved it

[run it](https://play.golang.org/p/Sz9S395KTlh)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func other(c chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    time.Sleep(time.Second*1)
    c <- 455
    wg.Done()
}

func addInt(c chan int, d int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    c <- d
    wg.Done()
}
func main() {

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    myChanel := make(chan int)

    wg.Add(2)

    go addInt(myChanel, 5, &wg)
    go other(myChanel, &wg)

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(myChanel)
    }()

    for v := range myChanel {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }

}
```